# Spring getSingleResult() and getResultList() exceptions when using createSQLQuery

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this code that i am using to get login a mobile device user and to do that i am checking against some user input and hoping to query the table if the string exists or not. I was expecting to have some problems with `getSingleResult()` but not with `getResultList`.

This is the code

```
//Mobile Login
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = { "/mobileloginbackend" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String mobilelogin(@RequestParam String ssoId,@RequestParam String password) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("select password from accounts where sso_id=:name");
        theQuery.setParameter("name", ssoId);
        List list = theQuery.getResultList();
        String stored_password = list.get(0).toString();

        if(list.isEmpty()){
            return "that user does not exist";
        }

        if(list.size() == 0){
        return "that user does not exist";  
        }

        if(passwordEncoder.matches(password,stored_password)){
            return "successful login";
        }
        else{
            return "wrong credentials";
        }

        }
```

This two lines are the ones that give the exception

```
if(list.isEmpty()){
            return "that user does not exist";
        }

        if(list.size() == 0){
        return "that user does not exist";  
        }
```

and i am getting error 500(internal server error).

How can i make this work?.

Comment: add the stack tracer

Comment: Paste your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

If you list is indeed empty, are you not getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` from this line :

`String stored_password = list.get(0).toString();`

You should first check if it's not empty before trying to fetch the first element.

By the way doing `if(list.isEmpty())` and `if(list.size() == 0)` is exactly the same.

Comment: I agree they are the same,but also this String stored_password = list.get(0); is an error

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me

```
        //Mobile Login
        //import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = { "/mobileloginbackend" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String mobilelogin(@RequestParam String ssoId,@RequestParam String password) {

        try {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("select password from accounts where sso_id=:name");
        theQuery.setParameter("name", ssoId);
        String stored_password = theQuery.getSingleResult().toString();
        if(passwordEncoder.matches(password,stored_password)){
            return "successful login";
        }
        else{
            return "wrong credentials";
        }
          }
       catch (NoResultException e) { 
         return "That user does not exist.";
         }

        }
```